# How would I access the tableView in a non tableView method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

how would I access this code for determining which tableView is being used in a non tableView method?

I know how to use it in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method but how would I access it in a method I make?

do I use `UITableView` instead of tableView?

```
-(void)myMethod {

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableViewNode])
        {

        }
        if ([tableView isEqual:self.tableViewCities])
        {

        }

}
```

I'm looking to see if a tableView is scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and then perform an action.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

//    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");

    if ([UITableView isEqual:self.tableViewNode])
    {
        float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
        if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
        {
            index ++;
            [self getFeed:index];
        }
    }
    if ([UITableView isEqual:self.tableViewCities])
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: *"I'm looking to see if a tableView is scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:"* What does this mean? Are you just trying to check if the scroll view invoking the delegate method is the same as the one referenced by one of the two table view properties (`tableViewNode` or `tableViewCities`)? And how does the scroll view delegate method relate to your custom, no-parameter method `myMethod`?

Comment: when self.tableViewNode scrolls to the bottom I do some pagination and add 10 more items to the table. at the moment if you scroll either table to the bottom the pagination triggers. I would like to do this to both tables but with different data

Comment: basically I want to detect when UITableView did scroll to bottom but I have two tables and need to know which one is being scrolled and hits bottom. thanks :)

Comment: I think I understand. I still don't really see how that relates to `myMethod`. But I've tried to give a guess in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method, you can compare the `scrollView` argument to the table view properties.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.firstTableView == scrollView) {
        // respond to firstTableView scrolling
    }
    else if (self.secondTableView == scrollView) {
        // respond to secondTableView scrolling
    }
}
```

If you need to implement methods in your table view's delegate that are called by the delegate methods, but behave differently based on which table view called the calling method, then you should make those methods take a table view parameter and always pass the the table view argument of the delegate methods when you call them. Inside these methods, compare `tableView` to your properties.

```
- (void)myMethod:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (self.firstTableView == tableView) {
        // do something for firstTableView
    }
    else if (self.secondTableView == tableView) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

If you needed to call `myMethod:` from `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for instance, you'd do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self myMethod:tableView];
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly. thanks I didn't know that u could do it that way :)